# Extract a dataframe from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (say "tst" in the code below) from which, I want to construct a new dataframe (that I named by "WhatIwant"). In brief : I've dropped some rows and columns to find a reduced dataframe. Is there any (pythonic) way to do it directly aside from dropping rows and columns ?

```
tst = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.arange(7), 'b': np.arange(8,15), 'c': np.arange(16,23), 'd': np.arange(24,31)})
```

What I want to find:

```
WhatIwant = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,3,5], 'c': [16,19,21], 'd': [24,27,29]})
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the logic to go from `tst` to `whatIwant` ? @AChampion might want to select only `a, c, d` in columns conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas has got the `loc` accessor for just these purposes

```
>>> tst.loc[(0, 3, 5), ('a', 'c', 'd')]
a   c   d
0  0  16  24
3  3  19  27
5  5  21  29
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew about the the loc accessor but didn't know we can use it that way!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you just want rows `0, 3, 5` and not column `b` then:

```
In []:
WhatIwant = tst.loc[[0,3,5], tst.columns != 'b'].reset_index(drop=True)
WhatIwant

Out[]:
   a   c   d
0  0  16  24
1  3  19  27
2  5  21  29
```

Comment: WhatIwant.reset_index(drop=True)